# firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP fires child_changed twice, which one is correct?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On setting `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` in a ref, child_changed is called twice, is one call local and another the actual server time?

I am handling the double call by using a:

```
ref.once...
```

call, and am wondering if only grabbing the first `child_change` is incorrect? If so, how to handle only the second call? Thanks.

edit:

```
//If once is the local time, how do I only do something
//with the second child_changed call?
ref.once("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
   //do something with snapshot.val().fbTime;
});

ref.push({"fbTime": firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP});
```

edit #2:

```
//Using .on instead of .once, this listener only fires once.
//Is this the local estimate?
ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
   //do something with snapshot.val().fbTime;
});

//causes "child_changed" to be fired once.
ref.push({"fbTime": firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP});
```

edit #3:

fixed ref object key syntax.

Comment: The first value is a client-side estimate. The second value is the value from the server. Aside from that, it's unclear what you're asking. Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem you're trying to solve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to say more.

Comment: Hopefully this makes it clearer. I need to do something with the time I receive in the "child_changed" listener. I am trying to figure out how to "do something" with only the correct value.

Comment: If you need convincing that the single value that comes from your edit#2 code is that stored in Firebase, you can compare your console value with the data at https://console.firebase.google.com/project/{your-project-id}/database/data

Answer (score 0):

The last one is correct.
The first one is approximate delay between local-time and the server
The second one is the actual correct one.

Please find the note below:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2461