# Calling ArrayList set method in onChildChanged creates duplicate record with updated record

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist

```
    ArrayList<String> mKeys = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Complaint> objectItems = new ArrayList<>();



public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    String key_use = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    mKeys.add(key_use);
                    //some codes

                    objectItems.add(0, objectItem);
                    customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
        }

 public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                String key_use = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                int index = mKeys.indexOf(key_use);

                //some codes
                objectItems.set(index, objectItem);
                customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

This is working well but the set method in onChildChanged creates duplicate record after updating the record. It should only updates the record only at that particular index

Comment: The `set()` method can not add a new item. So when you're saying *creates duplicate record* what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding key at the end of the list and object at the start of the list. Hence they both doesn't have same position

Please change your code to

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                String key_use = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                mKeys.add(key_use);
                //some codes
                // This is the change. Add the item at the en but not at the start
                objectItems.add(objectItem);
                customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    }
```

Comment: now i'm getting this `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1` sometimes the values of index and length changes in the error. Is there a better way to get the index of the particular child that changed in firebase?

Comment: Better to use a HAshMap rather than maintaining 2 lists
Use 

map.put(key, value)

Comment: thanks, working. But this prevent me from adding items to the end of the arraylist, i can't display the latest items on a listview. Can anything be done to achieve this while still getting the specific child index?

Comment: Use LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap. It should behave according to your needs. If not, post your code. Can look at it

Answer (score 0):

If you used

> FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

when you sent it to the database.

it will create children also serverTimestamp() child then it will trigger on your onChildAdded and it will trigger on your onChildChanged next.

As Frank van Puffelen said here [firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP fires child_changed twice, which one is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852827/firebase-database-servervalue-timestamp-fires-child-changed-twice-which-one-is)

> The first value is a client-side estimate. The second value is the value from the server. Aside from that, it's unclear what you're asking. Without seeing the minimal code that reproduces the problem you're trying to solve, it's impossible to say more. – Frank van Puffelen

So that why you got an duplicate record.

Comment: now i'm getting this java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1 sometimes the values of index and length changes in the error. Is there a better way to get the index of the particular child that changed in firebase?

Comment: I think you should keep key in an object instead of storing in difference list. example add  @ exclude ‘private String key’ then ‘objectItem.setKey(datasnapshot.getKey());’. Note that the @exclude use when you not want this parameter appear in your database when create a new record.